# Android: Random Number list to an actual number

Tags: android, random, phone-number

My app has a section that will generate random numbers so that the numbers can be combined as an 11 digit number so that it can send out a phone call.

So far I have this:

```
Random rand = new Random();

ArrayList<Integer> randNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) //randNumber.add(i);
{
    int number = rand.nextInt(10);
    randNumber.add(number);
    Log.d("random", "number:" + number);
    Log.d("Random", "list" + randNumber);   
}

this.setResultData("12345678910");

final String newNumber = this.getResultData();
```

The random numbers generated will go in place of "12345678910".

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and nasty solution. You could also create a method that will take your final ArrayList and join the contents together into a String using a similar process like I've shown. A method like this may already exist, but I don't know what it will be called.

```
Random rand = new Random();

ArrayList<Integer> randNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
StringBuilder newNumber = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) //randNumber.add(i);
{
    int number = rand.nextInt(10);
    randNumber.add(number);
    newNumber.append(number);
    Log.d("random", "number:" + number);
    Log.d("Random", "list" + randNumber);   
}

//this.setResultData("12345678910");
this.setResultData(newNumber.toString());

final String newNumber = this.getResultData();
```

Comment: If you choose this approach, use [StringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of String.

Comment: Updated to use StringBuilder instead.

Comment: That's worked like a charm, thank you! I knew it was gonna be simple as well lol

Comment: Glad it works for you. The simplest things normally catch us out. Could you up-vote and accept the answer, please?